# HEVC File bigger after converting from h264

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'm currently working an an automated Python script for indexing and converting all my movies and episodes with `ffmpeg`. I use `subprocess.call()` for running the `ffmpeg` command and tested this command with some movies. As expected the big `h264` files were converted to merely one third of what they used to have.

But now that I was testing the method I found that a converted episode (about 400MB in h264) had over 1,6GB in hevc. I have absolutely no idea why the new file would be that much bigger in hevc.
This is my code:

```
def convert(path):
    outvid = path.strip(".mkv") + "h265.mkv"

    cmd = ["ffmpeg", "-i", path, "-map", "0", "-map_metadata", "0", "-map_chapters", "0", "-c:v", "libx265",
           "-c:a", "copy", "-c:s", "copy", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-x265-params", "lossless=1", outvid]
    subprocess.call(cmd)

convert("/Volumes/2TB/Black Butler/Season 1/Black Butler S01E01.mkv")
```

I don't have that much experience with `ffmpeg`, nor with `subprocess`. This is one of my first bigger projects. I hope someone can tell me what the problem might be.

**UPDATE**
Problem applies only for small video files. I now just check for the file size and skip the small files. Wouldn't have made much of a difference anyway.

[image: Size Comparison]

Comment: why are you passing  `-preset ultrafast` and `-x265-params lossless=1` to ffmpeg?  these will both **severely** affect ffmpeg's ability to produce a small file

Comment: Well... in another stackoverflow thread I read about these arguments for keeping original quality while still not using too much time. But I just removed both of the arguments completely (I guess the standards will take over then) and in fact the file is from 400MB to 98MB but the quality is absolutely sh*tty. Then I tried again with only lossless on and yes, quality is fine but file is 1.45GB. Any more parameters I could try?

Comment: the defaults change in different versions of ffmpeg…  there are lots of tradeoffs here hence making it do the "right thing" depends on what you're trying to do (i.e. playback profiles, how much CPU time to spend encoding).  read through the https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265 and the H264 pages to see some of the options.  `-preset medium -crf 28` might help, but these should be default unless you have an old version of ffmpeg

Comment: it might be worth playing with something like handbrake.fr to get an idea for the effect different options have on encoding

Comment: I'm running the latest ffmpeg version but I'll take a look on the suggested sites. Maybe I'll find some handy parameters. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are you re-encoding?

Comment: I‘m going to shrink my movie collection’s size. So I can fit more movies an a smaller NAS.